# Operand type clash: int is incompatible with DaysAndHours

Tags: c#, sql-server, int, sqlexception

**Exception:** `Operand type clash: int is incompatible with DaysAndHours    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`

The above exception is getting when I add int type value to SQL parameters.How to pass the int value to sql parameters.

**C# code:**

```
 public bool VendorDaysAndHoursInfoByMemberID(UpdateVendaorDaysAndHoursDM updateVendaorDaysAndHoursDM)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("VendorRepository.vendorDaysAndHoursInfoByMemberID method called!!!");
            var memberId = updateVendaorDaysAndHoursDM.MemberID;

            var vendorDaysAndHoursDMsList = updateVendaorDaysAndHoursDM.DaysAndHours.Select(c => c).Select(c => c).ToList();
            DataTable dtVendorDaysAndHoursDMsList = DataReaderToList.ToDataTable<DaysAndHoursDM>(vendorDaysAndHoursDMsList);

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetComapnyConnection.ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (var transaction = conn.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("exec VendorDaysAndHoursInfoByMemberID @MemberID, @DaysAndHours", conn, transaction);

                        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                        cmd.Transaction = transaction;

                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MemberID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = memberId;

                        //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                        //{
                        //    ParameterName = "@MemberID",
                        //    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured,
                        //    Value = memberId,
                        //    TypeName = "MemberID"
                        //});

                        var pDaysAndHoursDMsList = new SqlParameter("@DaysAndHours", SqlDbType.Structured);
                        pDaysAndHoursDMsList.TypeName = "DaysAndHours";
                        if (dtVendorDaysAndHoursDMsList.Rows.Count == 0)
                            pDaysAndHoursDMsList.Value = null;
                        else
                            pDaysAndHoursDMsList.Value = dtVendorDaysAndHoursDMsList;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(pDaysAndHoursDMsList);
                        var dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        var isResult = DataReaderToList.DataReaderMapToList<bool>(dataReader);

                        dataReader.Dispose();

                        transaction.Commit();

                        conn.Close();

                        return true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                        conn.Close();
                        _logger.LogError(e.Message);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

I need to post data in the below format.

```
{ 
"MemberID":"a7f1819db38ccb5e03ad52396eafa5ac"                    ,
"DaysAndHours":[
                    {"DayName":"Sunday","StartTime":"08:00:00","EndTime":"17:00:00","Available":false},
                    {"DayName":"Monday","StartTime":"08:00:00","EndTime":"17:00:00","Available":true},
                    {"DayName":"Tuesday","StartTime":"08:00:00","EndTime":"17:00:00","Available":true},
                    {"DayName":"Wednesday","StartTime":"08:00:00","EndTime":"17:00:00","Available":true},
                    {"DayName":"Thursday","StartTime":"08:00:00","EndTime":"17:00:00","Available":true},
                    {"DayName":"Friday","StartTime":"08:00:00","EndTime":"17:00:00","Available":true},
                    {"DayName":"Saturday","StartTime":"08:00:00","EndTime":"19:00:00","Available":true}
                   ]
    }
```

How to pass the int value to SQL parameters in above format.

Stored Procedure:

```
Create proc [dbo].[VendorDaysAndHoursInfoByMemberID]
(
@DaysAndHours as [dbo].DaysAndHours readonly,
@MemberID int,
@IsSuccess bit= 'false' output
)
as begin
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    update DaysAndHours  set
    DaysAndHours.DayName=DaysAndHoursData.DayName,
    DaysAndHours.StartTime=DaysAndHoursData.StartTime,
    DaysAndHours.EndTime=DaysAndHoursData.EndTime,
    DaysAndHours.Available=DaysAndHoursData.Available

    from  @DaysAndHours DaysAndHoursData
 where MemberID = @MemberID;

 set @IsSuccess = 'true' 

End    
return @IsSuccess
```

Code is not displaying errors.But `isResult` is getting count zero which is below of DataReader.

[image]

Comment: Whats the definition of your stored procedure ?

Comment: check Store procedure parameter and use varchar in it

Comment: @MichaelRandall  added stored procedure

Comment: @Mano added stored procedure.Please check once

Comment: keep memberid as the first parameter in your SP. @MemberID int,@DaysAndHours as [dbo].DaysAndHours readonly,

Comment: @Atk Did the as per you told.Now getting this exception.
`System.InvalidCastException: Failed to convert parameter value from a Int32 to a IEnumerable1. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.Int32' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1`

Comment: where are you getting this error. on which line?

Comment: your `AddWithValue` syntax is incorrect try `AddWithValue("@MemberID", memberId);` (no `.Value` afterwards)

Comment: @Atk `var dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();` line getting error

Comment: @jalsh tried.getting error `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Operand type clash: int is incompatible with DaysAndHours` when i use `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MemberID",memberID);`

Comment: @Priyanka I think your SQL command is wrong. Try this, 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("VendorDaysAndHoursInfoByMemberID", conn, transaction);

Comment: @Atk Now errors not coming. But `isResult` value is getting zero. Can you please check my store procedure once. Based on `memberID` I want to update the `DaysAndHours` table data.

Comment: @IsSuccess bit= 0 output
set IsSuccess = 1
Remove single quotes since it is bit datatype

Answer (score 0):

Sql Command is not properly configured. Try this

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("VendorDaysAndHoursInfoByMemberID", conn, transaction);
```

Stored Procedure code

```
Create proc [dbo].[VendorDaysAndHoursInfoByMemberID]
(
@DaysAndHours as [dbo].DaysAndHours readonly,
@MemberID int,
@IsSuccess bit= 0 output
)
as begin
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    update DaysAndHours  set
        DayName=@DaysAndHours.DayName,
        StartTime=@DaysAndHours.StartTime,
        EndTime=@DaysAndHours.EndTime,
        Available=@DaysAndHours.Available
from DaysAndHours join @DaysAndHours
ON DaysAndHours.MemberID =@DaysAndHours.MemberID 
 where MemberID = @MemberID;

 set @IsSuccess = 1 

End    
return @IsSuccess
```

Comment: Now see my stored procedure once.Need to update multiple rows in `DaysAndHours` at a time.But All rows is updating with one object of data only

Comment: Why are you using @DaysAndHours in your stored procedure?? And is DaysAndHours a physical table?

Comment: DaysAndHours is my physical table

Comment: I don't whow what is your requirement, but check i have updated my answer. Check it.

Comment: My requirement is need to update the all rows of `DaysAndHours` table with my posted data.I'm sending all rows of data to update the table.And each memberID has different `DaysAndHours` data.

Comment: I added my table columns picture.I'm sending only 4 properties in an object of the list.MemberID is the same for all objects.

Comment: @Priyanka Do you also have a type table with name DaysAndHours??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207834/discussion-between-priyanka-and-atk).